# VBA object-oriented programming

Tags: c++, excel, vba, dll

This question is an extension of a previous question: [Return an object in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641764/return-an-object-in-vba)

Now, I'd like to know how to declare and initialize the object in VBA. It seems like I'd do it like so:

```
Declare Function ConnectMe Lib "C:\Windows\System32\cm.dll" (ByVal Arg1 As String) As ConnectMe
Declare Function login Lib "C:\Windows\System32\cm.dll" (ByVal Arg1 As String, ByVal Arg2 As String) As Boolean
```

Then, below this line, I could use this code:

```
dim cm as new ConnectMe

cm.ConnectMe("216.239.51.99")

cm.login("username","password")
```

However, when I do this, it gives me a "User-defined type not defined" error. How can I declare this C++ class appropriately so that I can create and use an instance in VBA?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is never going to work as it is. If you want to create a class in C++ under Windows and use it in any other programming language that is not C++, (VB for example) the "normal" approach is to create a [COM class](http://www.microsoft.com/com/default.mspx) or an [ActiveX control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751972%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Why_Are_ActiveX_Cont) if you need to draw graphics.

You may also find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987010/how-to-pass-string-array-from-c-c-dll-to-vba-excel/1003195#1003195) in SO helpful.

Answer (score 0):

i here again :D

To use this code with your function use:

```
Dim cm as Object

set cm = ConnectMe("parameter")

if cm.login("username","password") then 
     msgbox "Connect!",vbinformation
else
     msgbox "not connect!",vbinformation
end if
```

Comment: But how do I declare the function to be available? I'm thinking @yms is correct, that I'm going to need to approach this from an entirely different angle.

Comment: Sam look this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687915.aspx in this page has same answer.

Comment: I found what I believe you're referring to: "[Public | Private] Declare Function name Lib "libname" [Alias "aliasname"] [([arglist])] [As type]" However, when I try to specify the 'ConnectMe' class with "Declare Function ConnectMe Lib "C:\Windows\System32\cm.dll" (ByVal Arg1 As String) As ConnectMe" it complains about the user-defined type. Any suggestions?

Comment: You registered your DLL with REGSVR32 C:\windows\System32\cm.dll ?

Comment: That page does not mention references to classes or objects. As I mentioned in my answer, this problem is not only for C++ to VBA. An instace of a (non-COM) C++ class cannot be used directly in any other programming language.

Comment: When I do it says that it "was loaded but the entry-point DLLRegisterServer was not found".

Comment: @Sam That is what happens when you try to register a dll that does ot contain any COM class. REGSVR32 is meant to be used with COM dlls.

Comment: By the way, even if you do have a COM dll, creating instances of a COM class by calling an exported function of the dll will not work either. VB has its own way of creating COM objects.

Comment: Of course "an instance of a (non-COM) C++ class can be used directly in any other programming language" it just takes more work, and a knowledge of the class interface used by your compiler. There is nothing magic about a C++ class: it's just code and memory.